# EnCrypt PHP -> C#

Tags: c#, php

I would like to convert php code to c# code :

The PHP Code :

```
$key = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$message = "MY MESSAGE";

$iv_length = mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB );
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv( $iv_length, MCRYPT_RAND );
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv );
$result = base64_encode( $iv . $encrypted );
```

The C# Code :

```
public static string Encrypt(string message, string key)
{
    var text = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
    using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        aes.BlockSize = 256;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key), aes.IV);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(text, 0, text.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
                var byteResult = new byte[aes.IV.Length + ms.ToArray().Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(aes.IV, 0, byteResult, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(ms.ToArray(), 0, byteResult, aes.IV.Length, ms.ToArray().Length);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(byteResult);
        }

    }
}
```

But it does not work.
The encoded string from C# is not accepted by php code

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Define "But it does not work." what happens.

Comment: The result is not accepted by php for uncrypt